# I need to get number of array's elements?

Tags: java

For example this array has 5 element.

```
int saffet[] = {0,2,4,6,8};
```

And this has 2

```
int saffet[] = {0,2};
```

How can i get such as above?
(question is maybe simple because I'm learning java new)

Comment: google is your friend! i just searched for 'java array length' and got loads of useful links. ps - i don't know java but could have guessed at 'length' being the answer based on experience with ither programming languages

Comment: seriously? Did you try googling? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: In the future, Google 'java array' should get you to an API.  Also, using an IDE with autocomplete is a godsend when learning a language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, it's easy :)

```
int length = saffet.length;
```

Note that it's recommended that you keep the type information together when declaring a variable (or parameter, return type etc) - while your declaration is *correct*, this is preferred:

```
int[] saffet = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 };
```

See [chapter 10 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html) for more details on arrays.